# Is it recommended to use multiple URLs in schema.registry.url?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Documentation here https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html mentions a possibility to use a single URL, which implies the possibility to use multiple too, comma-separated, however, the question is what is recommended and why, use something like F5, or simply comma-separated URLs?

I tested comma-separated URLs with both kafka-avro-console-producer and kafka-avro-console-consumer, and while the latter always behaves as expected, the former sometimes returns (prints to the console) >>ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint<< when one of URLs is bad, although it produces the message to Kafka, and it doesn't crash. I'd rather that it doesn't do that, but such an exception can always be ignored in real application code. It actually prints a whole error stack, not just these few words. I've also seen this:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/711

We would use 3 URLs as a config parameter value, what do you think about it?

We use Java clients, code looks like this:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-group");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://kafka1:8081,http://kafka2:8081,http://kafka3:8081");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
```

So, let's say we have 3 kafka broker server nodes, kafka1, kafka2 and kafka3, and we started one instance of schema registry on each of them, shall we use the similar syntax to define SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG as we did for BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG in the example above, or shall we use external load balancer for example F5, or round robin DNS, and have it provide a single ipaddr/alias (like schema_registry_loadbalanced in the example below) that resolves to kafka1, kafka2 and kafka3? That would be utilized in application code like this:

```
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://schema_registry_loadbalanced:8081");
```

For kafka connection, we don't think external load balancer provides much benefit, but for schema registry we are not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your client, but the Java properties, at least, are set to take in a configuration type as a URL list.

Where I am working, the registries are being a load-balancer, so it's one URL anyway.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, but I didn't quite get what you say how you use it exactly, multiple urls in schema.registry.url directly, or one url provided by external means, that's why I added some details to the question to explicate what is our idea what are the options here.

Comment: Multiple URLs are the intended design in the source code. There is nothing wrong with putting it behind a load balancer.